# Jekyll custom variable outputting incorrect value

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll 4.1.1 and have a custom variable in my `_config.yml` file in the following format:

```yaml
brand:
  telephone     : 01444555666
```

For some reason if my number starts with `01` then when compiled or running `jekyll serve` I get a completely different value, but if I change the starting value from `01` to for instance `08` and re-compile, then it works...

I'm getting the value of `210951094` outputted to my page with the above, is Jekyll treating the starting characters as some function to generate a random number here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leading `0` treats the number as *octal*, just like in Ruby:

```rb
01444555666
#=> 210951094
```

Turning your telephone number into a string should fix it:

```yaml
brand:
  telephone: '01444555666'
```